# Android AsyncTask error while loading GoogleMap 2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

My code was working fine but since i implemented asynctask it showing the following error. actually i want to show the progress bar till map loads thats why putt all code in asynctask

Java File

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.CursorJoiner.Result;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Tab_location extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ProgressBar myprogress;


    Thread load;
    int waittym= 1000;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_location);



   progress A1 = new progress();
    A1.execute();              





   }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        progress A1 = new progress();
        A1.execute();

    }

    public void loadMap( )
    {


            if(mMap!=null)
            {
                return;
            }


            mMap=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            //mMap.addMarker(  new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng( 28.585726000000000000, 77.311042000000040000)).title("Noida Sec 15").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker()));
            if(mMap==null)
            {
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    }



    public class progress extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

               // Showing status
                        loadMap();
                        Log.i("after","Loadmap");
                        LocationManager  locationManager =(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                         Criteria criteria= new Criteria();

                         String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                         Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                          if(location!=null)
                             {
                            onLocationChanged(location);   
                                  }
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0,this);

            return null;
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            myprogress =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            myprogress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();

            LatLng latLng= new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14),2000,null);


        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
}
}
```

LOGCAT ERROR

```
        09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:197)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:197)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.location.LocationManager.wrapListener(LocationManager.java:820)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:833)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:430)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at com.example.tatadocomowi_fi.Tab_location$progress.doInBackground(Tab_location.java:84)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at com.example.tatadocomowi_fi.Tab_location$progress.doInBackground(Tab_location.java:1)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-08 03:01:30.232: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: You are doing UI related work by calling `loadMap();` within `doInBackground()`. Try to ignore UI related work within `doInBackground()`

Comment: will you please elaborate it?

Comment: just move this `loadMap();` from doInbackground() to onPreexecute(), u can't deal with views from a non-UI thread (which in ur case is the asyncTask)

Comment: but anyways, registering locationListener does not need asyncTask

Comment: Sir can you correct my code and post it..?

Comment: @user3853169 i have posted your answer from your original after moving some codes around, and it should have the progress working too

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class Tab_location extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ProgressBar myprogress;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_location);
        mMap=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager  locationManager =(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria= new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(location!=null)
        {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0,this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14),2000,null);


    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

Comment: m gonna post as answer.

Comment: it works without asynctask but i want to add progress bar till map loads thats why m using asyntask...can you tell me how show progress bar till map loads without usingasynctask

Comment: why are you block user interaction when you location is updated ?

Answer (score 0):

based on your request here is code changed to work with progress bar
it may have miner errors as its not compied, just moved codes around

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.CursorJoiner.Result;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Tab_location extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ProgressBar myprogress;

    // Thread load;
    // int waittym= 1000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_location);

        progress A1 = new progress();
        myprogress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        myprogress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        loadMap();
        registerLocationListener();
    }

    private boolean registerLocationListener() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
        Log.i("after", "Loadmap");
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

        return true;
        myprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        progress A1 = new progress();
        A1.execute();

    }

    public void loadMap() {
        if (mMap != null) {
            return;
        }

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        // mMap.addMarker( new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
        // 28.585726000000000000,
        // 77.311042000000040000)).title("Noida Sec 15").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker()));
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14), 2000, null);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: maybe your code related to progressBar is not correct, check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html